Can I convert the roots of a function to low points through integration?
I know that when you derive a function the local minima and maxima become the roots of the derivative. Knowing this, could I use the integral of a function in order to convert my roots into local minimas and maximas or would other random minimas and maximas appear? It is important for the roots to be the only extreme points

Those will be the only extreme points, keep in mind though that they don't have to be extrema, but they can be inflection points (or whatever they are called) when the function you integrate is tangent to the x-axis at some point
